# rendering bmp not appearing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

i can't seem to load a bitmap and display it :S ... does anyone know what is wrong here? my bmp is 256 x 265 in size. I currently can only see a black screen (nothing is being shown). Any help would be appreciated!

```
int DrawGLScene(GLvoid) // Here's Where We Do All The Drawing
{
    GLuint texture = LoadBMP("C:/Untitled.bmp");


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(2.8f, 2.8f); glVertex2f(2.8f, 2.8f);
    glTexCoord2d(2.8f, 2.8f); glVertex2f(2.8f, 2.8f);
    glTexCoord2d(2.8f, 2.8f); glVertex2f(2.8f, 2.8f);
    glTexCoord2d(2.8f, 2.8f); glVertex2f(2.8f, 2.8f);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    return TRUE;    // Keep Going
}


GLuint LoadBMP(const char *fileName)
{
    FILE *file;
    unsigned char header[54];
    unsigned int dataPos;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int width, height;
    unsigned char *data;


    file = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error: Invaild file path!", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    if (fread(header, 1, 54, file) != 54)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error: Invaild file!", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    if (header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M')
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error: Invaild file!", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    dataPos = (int)&(header[0x0A]);
    size = (int)&(header[0x22]);
    width = (int)&(header[0x12]);
    height = (int)&(header[0x16]);

    if (size == NULL)
        size = width * height * 3;
    if (dataPos == NULL)
        dataPos = 54;

    data = new unsigned char[size];

    fread(data, 1, size, file);

    fclose(file);


    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);


    return texture;
}
```

Comment: Windows has [BITMAPFILEHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx) and [BITMAPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375(v=vs.85).aspx). Use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you do not see anything, you are using the same texture coordinate for every vertex :)

Texture coordinates in OpenGL (unless you are using something like a special ***rectangle texture***) are normalized in the range **0.0** - **1.0**. Where (**0.0**, **0.0**) represents the bottom-left corner of the image and (**1.0**, **1.0**) represents the top-right. You should consider stretching the image over your quad exactly one time, so use a combination of all four corners for your coordinates.

Also, use `glTexCoord2f (...)` since you are clearly using single-precision floating-point coordinates and not double-precision.

#### Consider this instead:

```
glBegin( GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f (0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f (-1.0f, -1.0f);
  glTexCoord2f (0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f (-1.0f,  1.0f);
  glTexCoord2f (1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f ( 1.0f,  1.0f);
  glTexCoord2f (1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f ( 1.0f, -1.0f);
glEnd ();
```

#### This code addresses ***two*** issues:

1. It will stretch your bitmap over the quad exactly one time
2. The vertex coordinates will cover your entire viewport

Comment: hmm... i tried the code you have.. but still no luck. only see a black screen. any other ideas? thanks for the response!

Comment: @BlueMonster: Well, I assume you are clearing the color buffer each frame, and swapping buffers (if using double buffering)? If you have any extra setup or drawing code, you should include it in the question. I would clear the color buffer to something like red, then draw this and see if at the very least the color changes - then you can narrow it down to texture issues.

Comment: hmm yes i do have the double buffering.. i have no issue with rendering a 3d shape... and even spinning it. it's just when adding in the texture that i get a problem where nothing on the screen changes - ie no texture appears